# Do AS3 socket event listeners require function scope where they are defined to end?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, events, actionscript

Say we have a function and a socket declared in it. We called `connect` on it. Now we called `addEventListener` on to connect.

In theory we could set function provided to eventDispatcher to change a class variable while a function that originally called `addEventListener` could be locked on that variable (alike `while(!class_instancce.is_connected)`).

My question is: will function passed to `addEventListener` be called of flash run time will wait for a function that is "on wait" to end?

Comment: Or right after `socket.connect` if all is ok we get `socked.connected == true` inside same function scope?

Comment: there should be no while.  ultimately, there can be only one (cheap highlander plug).  it should be listener for connect... then do stuff.  while is great for inline.. i.e. if you were in a onData event and you were listening for more socket info.. but connect doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

The function that is passed to addEventListener will run as soon as whatever event you're listening for is dispatched by the instance you're listening to (if there are multiple listeners, this will be based on event priority.

It sounds to me like you want to try to make the socket connection happen synchronously. You can't do this with sockets, though there are [some things](http://www.funky-monkey.nl/blog/2009/01/13/synchronous-vs-asynchonous/) in AS that you can force to be synchronous.

Honestly, you should get comfortable with event-driven architecture sooner rather than later, because it makes all sorts of OOP loveliness possible for you.

You can use anonymous functions if you're bound and determined. You can research it yourself. I think it's a bad habit unless you *really* know what you're doing and how to avoid memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Ah... so a bit more info: there is new version of Alchemy/Flascc and it has no out of box unix socket support for the moment. So to support old C/C++ code base I need to create sync wrapper around AS3 sockets. I wonder about 2 things: can AS3 sockets be used in sync manner out of the box or if not how to create sync connect method for them.

Comment: Consider using something like the future value pattern described here http://web.archive.org/web/20070403033325/http://johnwilger.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how sockets work in AS3:

First create the socket and add Listeners:

```
_socket = new Socket();
// or if secure
_socket = new TLSSocket();
_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
_socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
// also add listeners for errors, close etc
_socket.connect(myURL, myPORT);

private function onConnect(event:Event):void{
    //connection is live now so do whatever like send something
    var request:String = "create a request here";
    _socket.writeUTFBytes(request);
    _socket.flush();
}

private function onData(event:ProgressEvent):void{
    //this gets called EVERY time new data comes over the socket
    // the socket will stay connected until you close it (or an error makes it drop)
    // here is how you read what came over the socket
    while(_socket.bytesAvailable){
        theData = _socket.readUTFBytes(_socket.bytesAvailable);
    }
    // now do something with the data
}
```

Hope that helps you with getting your sockets set up